# Not a Procedure, Really?

Tags: if-statement, scheme

I been trying to figure this out for like 2 hours now! please Consider the following code:

```
(define (PowListF list) 
  (PowListFHelp list (- (length list) 1)))

(define (FuncPow f n) 
  (if (= 0 n)
      f
      (lambda (x)
        (FuncPow (f (- n 1)) x))))

(define (PowListFHelp list n) 
  (if (= n 0)
      (list (list-ref list 0))
      (cons (FuncPow (list-ref list n) n)
            (PowListFHelp list (- n 1)))))
```

The rocket Scheme compilers give me error:
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (# #)
  arguments...:
   #

and it points to the (cons part...

and The following code, that uses the same if structure, does work:

```
(define (polyCheb n)
  (reverse (polyChebHelp n)))

(define (polyChebHelp n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (list (polyChebFunc n))
      (cons (polyChebFunc n)
            (polyChebHelp (- n 1)))))

(define (polyChebFunc n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (lambda (x) 1)
      (if (= n 1) 
          (lambda (x) x)     
          (lambda (x)
            (- (* (* 2 x)
                  ((polyChebFunc(- n 1)) x))
               ((polyChebFunc(- n 2)) x))))))
```

EDIT: PowListF is being given list of functions as parameter, returns the same list s.t every function is composed with itself (its index + 1) times...

usage:
((list-ref (PowListF (list (lambda (x) x) (lambda (x) (expt x 2)))) 1) 2)
value should be 2^2^2=2^4=16

EDIT 2:

This was the solution :

```
(define (FuncPow f n) 
  (if (= 0 n)
      f
      (lambda (x) (f ((FuncPow f (- n 1)) x)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with: `(FuncPow(f (- n 1)) x)`

The result of calling `f` must be procedure (I assume this as you return a procedure).

You further then 'assign' `f` as: `(list-ref list n)`.

Comment: it does return procedure doesnt it?

Comment: my assumptaion is that list is list of procedures, so (list-ref list n) is the procedure at index n....

Comment: Then I guess it is the result of calling `(f (- n 1))` not returning one.

Comment: I edited the o.q to explain what i needed to do, maybe you can help me make it work..

Comment: Can you add a sample usage?

Comment: Can you see now why: `(FuncPow (lambda(x) x) 1)` does not return a procedure?

Comment: yeah i think i see it now!

Comment: Best way to deal with this is in the debugger or tracing the input/output. Refer to the Racket docs how to add tracing to a procedure. Alternatively, you can just check if `f` is indeed a procedure with `(procedure? f)`. If that is not the case, dump the parameter values and see when you gone wrong.